# Ruby Hash Key with Multiple Values: returning the minimum value in a timely manner

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested-loops

**UPDATE:** I was initially overwriting the hash keys, but have since resolved that. Thank you for everyone's input so far.

The issue now is how long the iterations are taking hours to produce data:

customers csv has **22,000** rows.

fiber csv has **170,000** rows.

```
fiber = CSV.read("fiber.csv", {headers: true})
customers = CSV.read("customers.csv", {headers: true})

hh = Hash.new { |hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }

#for each customer, loop through all the fiber coords
customers.each do |c|
  fiber.each do |f|
    hh[customer["cid"]].push Haversine.distance(c["lat"], c["lng"], f["lat"], f["lng"])
  end
end

vals = hh.map { |k, v| v.min } #returns the minimum value per row (which I want)
```

Since I'd like to use these values outside of the program/command line, I thought writing to a CSV would be an okay approach (other suggestions welcome).

However, since the above nested loop takes hours on hours to run without ever finishing, this is not an ideal approach.

```
CSV.open("hash_output.csv", "wb") {|csv| vals.each {|elem| csv << [elem]} }
```

Any ideas on how to speed this process up?

Comment: Right here you're overwriting the key each iteration `hh["customer_name"] = c["Last Name"]`

Comment: I think you should rethink your data structures ... do you want an array of hashes, each with a customer_name and feet_to_fiber list? Or possible a single hash with keys that are customer names and values that are feet_to_fiber vals?

Comment: I think a single hash with keys: key1 being customer_name, then key2 being feet_to_fiber which has many values.

Comment: If you make a hash with a single customer_name key and a single feet_to_fiber key, then you can only store one customer's data. You need to either make the keys dynamic (e.g. use .the name as the key, as @NateSHolland suggests), or use an array

Comment: I agree with @max that you reconsider your data structure, but I would like to point out that whenever you have two arrays, `a` and `b` and for each element of `a` you want to perform some operation on each element of `b` (as here), you should consider using the method [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product). By way of example, suppose `a = [:a, :b]` and `b = [1, 2]`. Then `c = a.product b #=> [[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:b, 1], [:b, 2]]`. You could then use `c` to construct the hash you want.

Comment: @DnfD what do you mean you would like to use the values outside of the program/command line? What exactly are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: @NateSHolland well since there's 21,000 customers, I need the  min value per customer: 21k results. Not like I could copy and paste 21k results from CLI to a file, so I thought a CSV would be best. Given the above implementation, I set up some logging and it's taking roughly 2-3 seconds PER customer for min value. So with 21k customers and 170k fiber pairs, I need to come up with a different type of algorithm I'm thinking.

Comment: So you want the min value per customer? You could speed the current algorithm up slightly if that’s what you’re looking for. Also could you mark my answer as correct since it properly answered the original question?

Comment: Just marked it :) Yes, looking to speed it up since if my rough calcs are correct: 2-3seconds per min val calculation within the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are overriding your name space with each loop. I would do something like this:

```
hh = Hash.new { |hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
#for each customer, loop through all the fiber coords
customers.each do |c|      
  fiber.each do |f|
    hh[c["last Name"]].push Haversine.distance(c["lat"], c["lng"], f["lat"], f["lng"])
  end
end
```

That way the keys will be the customer's last name and the values will be an array of distances.
So the resulting data structure will look like this:

```
{ 
   "DOE" => [922224.16, 920129.46, 919214.42],
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Nate, you are correct and was able to figure out the overwriting thing before checking your answer this morning (thank you, btw). The issue I'm running into now is there are so many customer lat long pairs (about 22k) and even more fiber pairs (170k). So it takes forever to run (had it going for a few hours last night with no end in sight). Will update my OP.

Comment: Yea this is a mxn algorithm to run so it's going to be pretty slow with numbers that large and it's going to take up a bunch of space in memory. You could also store all the customers in a DB and all the fiber values in a DB and then do a lookup and a calculation each time you want to know the value.